Maintain CTRL-CAPS swap when connecting to Ubuntu 24.04 with Desktop Sharing from Windows RDP client
I have a new installation of Ubuntu 24.04 on a Dell notebook. I added XKBOPTIONS="ctrl:swapcaps" in /etc/default/keyboard.
The swap works as expected from the local keyboard on the notebook.
I also have enabled Desktop Sharing, and can connect to the active desktop using a Windows RDP client. However, CTRL and CAPS are not swapped when I use the keyboard through the remote session.
The Windows system also has CTRL-CAPs swapped through registry settings.
If I use RDP to remote into a Windows system CTRL-CAPs are swapped normally.
Is there any way to control the swapping for the Desktop Sharing? Does it have a separate /etc/default/keyboard file?

This is still an issue.  There are no functioning VNC-like remote control program, so I'm forced to use RDP, which introduces this problem. Is there any other way to accomplish the ctrl-caps swap besides XKBOPTIONS?  I've tried 3rd party apps like input-remapper, but was unable to make it work.
